# Why can't I write the BindingList down on a .txt whilst using JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I am trying to add the content of my BindingList into a txt file. However, I always get the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What am I doing wrong? The text file is empty if that helps.

**Code:**

```
BindingList<Student> StudentCollection = new BindingList<Student>();

private void btnAddStudent_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Student StudentSave = new Student
    {
        ID = txtStudentID.Text,
        FirstName = txtFirstName.Text,
        LastName = txtLastName.Text,
        Age = nudAge.Value,
        Height = nudHeight.Value,
        Schoolclass = txtSchoolClass.Text,
        Gender = cbxGender.Text,
    };

    cbxStudentIDs.DataSource = StudentCollection;
    cbxStudentIDs.DisplayMember = "ID";
    StudentCollection.Add(StudentSave);

}
public class Student
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public decimal Age { get; set; }
    public decimal Height { get; set; }
    public string Schoolclass { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string studentCollectionString = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
    StudentCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BindingList<Student>>(studentCollectionString);
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    string studentCollectionString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(StudentCollection);
    File.WriteAllText(FilePath, studentCollectionString);
}
```

Comment: Which object is throwing the null reference exception? If you can provide either the stacktrace or run the debugger, and step through each line.

Comment: After this Line ``` StudentCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BindingList<Student>>(studentCollectionString);```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Hi, you are not suppose to directly assign StudentCollection to an result coz you will get the Null Exception. try the solution that I answered, its working for me

https://stackoverflow.com/a/61608673/1740399

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue**

This is where you will get the exception, as you mentioned text file is empty and `StudentCollection`  will be set to `null`

```
StudentCollection = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BindingList<Student>>(studentCollectionString);
```

**Solution**

You should change the code like this: the `?` will ensure that operation proceeds only if you have valid result in the text file.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BindingList<Student>>(studentCollectionString)?.ToList().ForEach(a => StudentCollection.Add(a));
```

Comment: This is the full Code for Form1_Load:

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string studentCollectionString = File.ReadAllText(FilePath);
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BindingList<Student>>(studentCollectionString)?.ToList().ForEach(a => StudentCollection.Add(a));
        }

Comment: You sir, are a Legend! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your Filepath does exist if not exist you should create the file then write to file, also ensure that your json is not empty

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.create?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Hey the Filepath does exist.